# Can we state the distribution of this Brownian motion as follows?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Consider the following Brownian motion:

$W(e^{2t})$

Where $t\in[0,\infty)$. What can we then say about how $W(t)$ is distributed? Could we say:

$W(e^{2t})\sim \sqrt{e^{2t}}N(0,1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that what you meant to say is that $(W_t)_{t\ge0}$ is a Brownian Motion and you're asking for the distribution of $\bar W_t := W_{e^{2t}}$ for all $t\ge 0$.

First note that $\bar W$ is **not** a Brownian Motion, as for all $0\le s\le t, \ \ \mathbb E [\bar W_t \bar W_s]=e^{2t} \wedge e^{2s} \ne t \wedge s$

However, $W$ is a Brownian Motion so it holds that for all $\bar t\ge 0$, $W_{\bar t} \sim \mathcal N(0,\bar t)$. In particular, for $\bar t := e^{2t}$,  $W_{e^{2t}} \sim \mathcal N(0,e^{2t})$.

So you were indeed correct.

Comment: Ah right, so could I do the following: $Y(t)=\int_{0}^{t}e^{-s}W(e^{2s})ds=\int_{0}^{t}e^{-s}\sqrt{e^{2s}}f(s)ds$ (where  is the density of a standard normal random variable)

Comment: No, be careful ! If you compute the integral of a stochastic process (here $e^{-t}W(e^{2t}$), you get a stochastic process, not a real number.   
So here your $Y(t)$ is a random variable and can't be equal to that integral on the right hand side which is a real number.